# I am trying to make a struct that references a variable within itself. How do i do this?

Tags: c, struct, initialization, definition

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    struct board
    {
        int length_x;
        int length_y;

        int board_size = length_x*length_y;
    };
    struct board chess_board ={
        8,8
    };
    return 0;
}
```

This returns the error

```
error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

I have made this a lot simpler that what I'm actually coding but all i want is when i make a struct it does that operation.

Comment: You can't ..... You'll have to do it by some code every time you make a new struct

Comment: Where in anything you've learned about C gave you the impression that the code you've posted is valid?

Comment: I just thought you could

Comment: @EvandroFilipe Unless you have a real good reason, it's actually a bad idea to have a member that is to be a product of two other members. Such things can get out of sync...

Comment: Did you expect that a change of `length_x` somewhere in your code would automatically update `board_size` ? It wont... you can't do such thing in C

Comment: i thought i could make a function to update them

Comment: @4386427 what would go wrong??

Comment: @EvandroFilipe If you initialize to `{8, 8, 64}` and the later do `length_x = 5;` and forget to update `board_size` you have a problem... Saving redundant data is nearly always a mistake (but there are exceptions...) **And...** in case you never change board size after initialization, you should make them `const`

Comment: So its only bad because i might forget to call the update function?

Comment: @4386427 I plan on changing it. remember this "case" is not the program i just simplified it and making it a chess board wasn't the smartest idea but i do plan to change the board size.

Comment: Doesn’t actual code involve `int something[]` at the structure tail? It wouldn’t be variable-sized otherwise. I suspect there will be some other question on this same program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C you may not initialize data members of a structure in the structure definition.

So this structure definition

```
struct board
{
    int length_x;
    int length_y;

    int board_size = length_x*length_y;
};
```

is incorrect.

You should write

```
struct board
{
    int length_x;
    int length_y;

    int board_size;
};
```

and then

```
struct board chess_board ={ 8, 8, 64 };
```

or for example

```
struct board chess_board =
{ 
    .length_x = 8, .length_y = 8, .board_size = 64 
};
```

It would be better to introduce a constant like

```
enum { N = 8 };
```

and then write

```
struct board chess_board =
{ 
    .length_x = N, .length_y = N, .board_size = N * N 
};
```

Or you could write a separate function that will initialize data members of an object of the structure type.

For example

```
void init_board( struct board *board, int n )
{
    board->length_x = n;
    board->length_y = n;
    board->board_size = n * n;
}
```

and after declaration of n object of the structure stype you could call the function

```
struct board chess_board;
init_board( &chess_board, 8 );
```

Comment: So is it just impossible to do anything like what i tried to do

Comment: or perhaps `struct board chess_board ={ 8, 8, 8 * 8 };`

Comment: Yeah i think i will use a function to init it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a macro to make a smart initializer

```
#define BOARD_INIT(N) { (N), (N), (N) * (N) }

struct board b = BOARD_INIT(8);
```

In C99 you could use compound literal and designated initializer to add some type-safety as well

```
#define BOARD_INIT(N) (struct board) { \
  .length_x = (N),                     \
  .length_y = (N),                     \
  .board_size = (N) * (N)              \
}
```

---

Actually, it is possible to make a "self-reference" because the name of the initialized variable is visible inside the initializer list.

```
struct board b = {
  .length_x = 8,
  .length_y = 8,
  .board_size = b.length_x * b.length_y,
};
```

According to [6.7.9p19](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p19):

> The initialization shall occur in initializer list order
> the values of `b.length_x` and `b.length_y` should be ready when `b.board_size` is initialized.